# nginx reading from a file that contains subject DNs

Tags: ssl, nginx, pki

So the intent, there will be a file that contains a list of Subject DNs and I would like nginx to read from this file and check if the incoming $ssl_client_s_dn response exists in that file.

Example file:

```
CN=client1.example.com d1230,OU=Servers,O=Company,L=Location,ST=Place,C=US
CN=client2.example.com d1230,OU=Servers,O=Company,L=Location,ST=Place,C=US
..etc..
```

Pseudo code:

```
if ($ssl_client_s_dn != contents of the file) {
   DO SOMETHING
}
```

Is that possible? I can't find anything that would handle this case.

Comment: Nginx cannot do this. You may be able to do something with a language extension (e.g. `Perl` or `lua`).

Comment: Darn. Ok thank you for your reply!